# Adding labels to QR codes

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a QR code generator. The user can create multiple QR codes.

I would like the user to be able to name each QR code (referred to as a checkpoint) by writing the desired checkpoint name in the text `input` field, clicking the `Assign Name` button and having the text `input` field disappear, being replaced by the name the user typed into the field.

The user can input checkpoint names, however, it only works for the first QR code printed, and the `label` only appears below the QR code. Below is the code that I have so far. Any help or suggestions to help me get the ball rolling on this would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

**Note:** If you try to run this to see the QR codes, you will have to enter something in the text field and press generate. They won't appear automatically.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    }

    section {
      margin: 50px auto;
      max-width: 350px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    textarea {
      width: 50%;
      height: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    #size {
      max-width: 64px;
    }

    label {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 140px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <h1>QR Code Generator</h1>
    <p>Enter a URL or some text bellow and hit the Generate button (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>)!</p>
    <textarea id="textarea" autofocus></textarea>
    <div class="block">
      <label for="size">Size (px):</label>
      <input align="left" id="size" type="number" value="150" min="50" max="500" step="50">
      <label for="amount">Amount of Labels:</label>
      <input align="left" id="amount" type="number" value="1" min="1" max="500" step="1">
      <button id="genQRcode">Generate</button>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="display: none;"></div>
  </section>
  <p id="demo" align="center"></p>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("cpname").value;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
  </script>
  <script id="template-qr-code" type="text/html">
    <p> <img id="qrcode" src="{{src}}" /></p>
    <label for="checkpoint"> Checkpoint Name:</label>
    <input id="cpname" type="text" value="">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Assign Name</button>
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea"),
        content = document.getElementById("content"),
        amount = document.getElementById("amount"),
        qrTemplate = document.getElementById('template-qr-code');

      function genQRcode() {
        var data = encodeURIComponent(textarea.value),
          size = document.getElementById("size").value,
          chart = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=" + size + "x" + size + "&choe=UTF-8&chld=L|0&chl=" + data;
        if (data === "") {
          alert("Please enter valid data!");
          textarea.focus();
          content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          for (var i = 0; i < amount.value; i++) {
            var qrSrc = qrTemplate.innerHTML;
            qrSrc = qrSrc.replace(new RegExp('{{src}}', 'g'), chart);
            qrSrc = qrSrc.replace(new RegExp('{{i}}', 'g'), i);
            content.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', qrSrc);
          }
          content.style.display = "";
        }
      }

      document.getElementById("genQRcode").addEventListener("click", genQRcode);
      document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
          genQRcode();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your click function

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("cpname").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

is getting and setting an element by ID. That will only ever affect a single element on the page (usually the first one that the browser runs into with that specific id). You need to use a different selector / way of getting the label you want to change because you can't reuse ids.

Basically you need to make your label fields distinct so you can actually select them